# Novice: Trying to memorize 1-4-5 chord progressions in varous keys when I discovered something. Is my understanding correct?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Absolute novice at music theory here so please be patient with me.

While doing some self-practice I observed the below pattern where a 1-4-5 chord progression of a major scale is exactly mapping to 1-6-8 if I consider all the twelve notes. I tried various keys and this mapping holds true for them all. It's a big aha moment for me but I want to know - Is this how it always is?

Thanks!

[image: 1-4-5 == 1-6-8 ?]

Comment: Well, yes. You've discovered that transposition preserves intervals, which is the cornerstone of its definition.

Comment: For me the analogous moment was learning in elementary school music class that the middle note of a major triad is always four semitones above the lowest note, and the top note always three semitones above the middle note.  That was on a piano, though, so it's maybe a less useful fact on the guitar, where chords aren't often voiced as root-position triads.

Comment: @phoog I'd say this sort of thing is good to know regardless of what instrument you play. (And it's not as if one always plays chords in root position on the piano. Dunno about more advanced pianists, but I play a lot of them in inversion for easy changes.) (Granted, it might be my old banjo experience talking, where I had to figure out any unfamiliar chord from its tones by myself. Somehow songbooks never included diagrams for banjo. Today's child might look it up on the internet instead, but, well... today's.) Helps with finding the melody if you know the chords, too - or vice versa.

Comment: @Divizna yes of course.  I don't really play guitar, though, so I don't have the same sense of how this knowledge relates to hand positions as I have for the keyboard.  As to keyboard chords in root position or not, indeed it's positively incorrect to play everything in root position when it comes to realizing figured bass, because that guarantees parallel fifths. But as a starting point to understand harmony and chord progression, I found it useful. I probably realized almost immediately that it's better to follow CEG in the right hand with CFA than FAC, but FAC was the starting point.

Comment: @phoog - one of my bugbears is that most guitar sites insist that chords (triads included) **must** be played in root position. Lots of folk on this site seem to agree with that stance as well. Not me!

Comment: @Tim I remember we once disagreed on this, but it was really just disagreement about notation - if I get it right, guitar chords are generally understood as root position unless specified with a bass tone. But of course I know that a lot of people prefer to play C/G when they see C notated. I sure don't disagree with the stance that you won't hurt the song when you do this. And to be honest I have no idea if I really hit the proper number of strings when strumming, so I may very well be playing D/A instead of D (on four strings) and C/E instead of C (on five).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is. The interval of a fourth is five semitones and a fifth is seven semitones. That's how it works.

What instrument do you play? On a guitar you get a helpful dot to mark the fourth and fifth (and also octave), on the fifth and seventh (and twelfth) fret. (Some even have more marks than that, but most have these three.)

Comment: Thank you. I play the guitar and knew about why the dots are where they are, but I never paid too much attention to the theory by writing it down on paper before today. This is so beautiful to finally understand!

Comment: @aliensurfer That's unfortunately common: teachers often explain some aspects of theory as pure notion. Not that they don't care about it, but sometimes they don't realize how much it's fundamental to ensure that their students realize (and become interested!) in the importance of these aspects. And it's actually quite difficult to achieve it: most of these aspects are fundamental for proper music knowledge, but cannot be properly understood until a certain overall experience is achieved. Focusing too much may be annoying to the student; underestimating it may become a problem in their future.

Comment: Those dots on frets 5 and 7 (and 12 for that matter) are really only much help in relation to *open* strings being the roots.

Comment: @Tim Hm, have I been doing it wrong all this time when I use them for orientation to place barré chords right? :o)) But in the context of this question, I mentioned them as a ready illustration that a fourth of fifth are a fixed number of semitones.